# Error when try to copy data from a column to another column in the same table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to copy the values from column "username" to column "email" in the same table using SQl tab from phpmyadmin but I get an error and I don't know how I can fix it.

I was try the ff code:

```
update `users`
set `username` = `email`
```

But I get the error:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'

Can anyone help me to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> username attribute added unique constraint that's why your query not
>   executed successfully. I think you have to need copy username
>   attribute data in email attribute and your query sequence is not
>   right. Please execute below query.

```
update `users`
set `email` = `username`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique constraint/index on `users.username` -- and entirely reasonable thing to do.  You are trying to set the user to an existing value.

You can use a query to find the values that are duplicated:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from users u2
              where u2.username = u.email and u2.username <> u.username
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy from username to Email then you should change the order in your statement:

```
update users set email = username
```